# ...this is what he used to do back in law school. Check me

Tags: verbs

In the movie "*The Wolf Of Wall Street*" there is a scene in which one of the friends of the  titular Wolf brings him to his friend from college who now runs a big bank in Switzerland in order to help him to deal with scrutiny of the FBI that his business is under. They have a little chit chat before the meeting and the bank owner is correcting his college buddy's spelling mistakes:

Bank Owner: Not Croy. Not Rue de la Croy.
It's Croix.

Friend of Wolf: See, this is what he used to do
back in law school. **Check me.**

Does "check" in this context mean:

1. : to slow or stop (something or someone) from doing something
   *She started to speak but then checked [=stopped] herself.
   The batter checked his swing. [=the batter started to swing and then stopped]* (Britannica Dictionary)
2. : to look at (something) carefully to find mistakes, problems, etc., or to make sure there is nothing wrong with it
   [+ object]
   *Make sure to check your spelling.
   She checked her makeup in the mirror.
   We should check the equipment to make sure that it's working properly.* (Britannica Dictionary)

?

Comment: Definitely (2), I'd say.

Comment: You seem to answer this yourself: "*the bank owner is **correcting** his college buddy's spelling mistakes*". What makes you doubt that interpretation?

Comment: @Joachim Well, there is a difference between the two definitions that I listed isn't it?

Comment: Thanks, Kate :)